# Windows7 run elasticsearch.bat Could not find any executable java binary. Please install java in your PATH or set JAVA_HOME

Tags: windows, elasticsearch, java-home

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6yJcU.png)

I want to use elasticsearch on Windows64. At first my Java version is not the same as the Java_Home.Then I reinstalled JAVA. And I found a solution said that the system will find JAVA under C:\ProgramData\Oracle\Java\javapath ,  So I replaced the latest java.exe javaw.exe , javaws.exe there, but the problem still exists.

I found below code in C:\elasticsearch-5.2.1\bin\elasticsearch could I do any changes to this to fix this problem?

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/y8gPN.png)

Comment: it turned out to be my JAVA_HOME has a ;

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried following?
Check your Environment variables for "JAVA_HOME" and "Path" inside system variables.
The location for JAVA_HOME is your the location of your jdk 
For Path variable you should add new  "...\Oracle\Java\javapath"

Comment: what do you mean by add new "...\Oracle\Java\javapath" ?

Comment: inside System variables double click variable named "Path" and inside it you will get a list of locations. If you cannot find "C:\ProgramData\Oracle\Java\javapath" among them then click new button and paste the location

Comment: there is a "C:\ProgramData\Oracle\Java\javapath" in Path

Comment: In my case the mistake was adding C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_144\bin instead **C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_144** to the path.

Comment: by JAVA_HOME it means path till 'jdk' or 'jre' folder (not till 'bin' folder)

Answer (score 1):

Add `C:\ProgramData\Oracle\Java\javapath;` to Path variable in Environment variable.

And Remove `JAVA_HOME`, as you have already Java Path to `Path`, you don't need to mention it twice.

It will surely help